# Why are session resumption and early data with TLS 1.3 not working for my NGINX 1.16 server?

Tags: freebsd, openssl, nginx

**Server Information:**

```
freebsd@FreeBSD-Website:~ % freebsd-version
12.0-RELEASE-p5
freebsd@FreeBSD-Website:~ % /usr/local/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1c 28 May 2019
freebsd@FreeBSD-Website:~ % nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.16.0
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1c 28 May 2019
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments:
.
.
.
```

**/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:**

```
user www;
.
.
.
http {
    .
    .
    .
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    .
    .
    .
    ssl_early_data on;
    ssl_session_tickets on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    .
    .
    .
}
.
.
.
```

**SSL Labs Snippet:**

[image: Both session resumption (tickets) and 0-RTT enabled show 'No'.]

**OpenSSL Output:**

```
freebsd@FreeBSD-Website:~ % set host=www.example.com
freebsd@FreeBSD-Website:~ % printf "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: $host\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" > request.txt
freebsd@FreeBSD-Website:~ % /usr/local/bin/openssl s_client -connect $host\:443 -tls1_3 -sess_out session.pem < request.txt
CONNECTED(00000003)
.
.
.
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 85...
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: 52...
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 86400 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - ...
    .
    .
    .
    Start Time: 1561132567
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 16384
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
.
.
.
---
read R BLOCK
DONE
freebsd@FreeBSD-Website:~ % /usr/local/bin/openssl s_client -connect $host\:443 -tls1_3 -sess_in session.pem -early_data request.txt
CONNECTED(00000003)
.
.
.
Reused, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
.
.
.
Early data was rejected
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
.
.
.
---
read R BLOCK
closed
```

**OpenSSL Observations:**

- `Session-ID-ctx` is blank when I sent the initial request. I don't know if it's supposed to be.
- I received two `Post-Handshake New Session Ticket`s after I sent the initial request; and the `Session-ID`, `Resumption PSK`, and `TLS session ticket`s were all different. I'm not sure why I didn't receive just one.
- When I sent the second request with the early data, it at least shows that the the handshake was reused.
- Since the early data was rejected, I received another `Post-Handshake New Session Ticket`; but this time only one. The `Session-ID`, `Resumption PSK`, and `TLS session ticket` were different than the previous two.
- The second request stalled at the end, and it took around 30 seconds for it to close. The initial request actually completed though which can be seen with the `DONE` line.

I know there is some weirdness with OpenSSL and NGINX (e.g., [not being able to specify TLS 1.3 ciphers with the `ssl_ciphers` directive](https://github.com/ssllabs/ssllabs-scan/issues/636)), but I'm not sure if this is another instance. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather unsatisfying answer, and one that can hardly be considered a "proof". I went ahead and enabled TLS 1.2 on my web server, and SSL Labs not only increased my site's grade from an A to an A+, but it also shows that session resumption is on. It still doesn't show 0-RTT as enabled.

I tested a couple of other sites that have TLS 1.3 enabled like https://scotthelme.co.uk and https://cromwell-intl.com, and they too show 0-RTT as not enabled. In the case of Scott's site, the servers are Cloudflare ones where they talk about having 0-RTT enabled.

This is all to say that I believe that TLS 1.3 is just too new for tests or even some of the functionality to work correctly (at least in OpenSSL and NGINX). I should add that I can't even add my site to https://hstspreload.org/ with only TLS 1.3. The only reason session resumption is displayed as on when I add TLS 1.2 to my server is that session resumption is a thing in TLS 1.2 unlike 0-RTT which is only a TLS 1.3 thing. I'm sure over the next few months this will be resolved though.